# PHP array stored in session not working if I redirect to another page

Tags: php

I am trying to check a form input data for errors -> store it in an array -> save it as a session and go back to the form page and show the errors.

But somehow the array stored in session doesn't work after I redirect back to Form page.
I just shows an empty array.

Here is the form page code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$error = $_SESSION['error'];
print_r($error);
unset($_SESSION['error']);
?>

//html form
```

And here is error check page code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$error = array();
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
else{
    array_push($error, 'Enter Email Address');
}

$_SESSION['error'] = $error;

header('location: form.php');

?>
```

Kindly help. Or any alternative?

Comment: add a [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) prior to the redirect.

Comment: Added. Still no change.

Comment: add exit; after header('location: form.php');

Comment: `array_push($error, 'Enter Email Address');` can be replaced with `$error[] = 'Enter Email Address';` for readability and a slight performance benefit as well.

Comment: Check if your server clock is proper.

Comment: It doesn't work either. Its so simple yet not working!

Comment: I would like to bring one more thing to notice that the session works fine if I don't store an array in it. If array is stored it shows empty array on next page.